# How to write query 3 statements in a single statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I use a single select query to execute the below 3 query in sql?

```
select COUNT(*)
from Product with(nolock)
where ProductNumber in ('704021872',
'704021871',
'704021870')

select COUNT(*)
from Product with(nolock)
where ProductNumber in ('704021872',
'704021871',
'704021870')
and column#3 is not null


select min(column#2), MAX(column#3) from Product
where ProductNumber in ('704021872',
'704021871',
'704021870')
and column#3 is not null
```

Comment: Please format your code snippets with the `{}` toolbar button or by indenting each line four (4) spaces.

Comment: There's a difference between MySQL and SQL Server, which are you using (looks like SQL Server, though).

Answer (score 6):

You basically just want aggregation functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select COUNT(*),
       COUNT(column#3),
       min(case when column#3 is not null then column#2 end), MAX(column#3)
from Product with(nolock)
where ProductNumber in ('704021872', '704021871', '704021870');
```

Note that this is pretty much standard SQL (except for the column names), so it will work in both MySQL and SQL Server.